# Kitchen light wiring

Tags: electrical, lighting

Just moved in and there is no kitchen light. There is a ground, two whites nutted together and two blacks AND a white nutted together. My new fixture has a standard hot and neutral. How do I connect?

Comment: Do you have a non contact voltage tester? E.g., https://www.amazon.com/Fluke-1AC-A1-II-VoltAlert-Non-Contact-Voltage/dp/B000EJ332O/ref=asc_df_B000EJ332O/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=312111908090&hvpos=1o3&hvnetw=g&hvrand=5084395277970259340&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9026945&hvtargid=aud-799711277694:pla-420856304134&psc=1

Comment: if forced to guess disconnect the white from the two blacks and connect to to the lamp hot, connect the lamp neutral to the two whites.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the light box?

Comment: You can also get a non contact voltage tester at Home Depot or Lowes or your local hardware store. This is a useful device. E.g., https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-Non-Contact-Voltage-Tester-NCVT-1SEN/100661787?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD27E%7C27-11_TOOLS_%26_ACCESSORIES%7CNA%7CLIA%7c71700000052584485%7c58700005051480447%7c92700044181773985&gclid=Cj0KCQjw5MLrBRClARIsAPG0WGzNNofGePlHD9VFesStRguTKFSKTVPBB4qjkClfHmFDpKjs8v3MDQsaAgabEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Does your new fixture have wire leads or does it have screw contacts? If the latter you may need short pieces of wire (commonly called pigtails) to connect it to this wiring.

Comment: The white nutted to the blacks could be the "switched hot" from a switch loop if this is an older home.  Of course this would all need to be verified with a multimeter - not a non-contact detector.

Comment: Does this fixture connect to a single switch or to a pair (or more) of switches at different locations?

Answer (score 1):

A lamp connects to **switched-hot** and **neutral**.

The two blacks and a white nutted together are **always-hot**.  This is not of interest to you, unless you want the lamp on 24x7. *Leave it alone*.

> For your information, there is an obsolete wiring technique called a "switch loop".  This is where power comes into the lamp, and the switch is a spur branch.   It carried 2 wires to the switch: always-hot went to the switch, and switched-hot came back. It goes without saying these two wires are in the same cable.
>
> Since only 2 wires were used, they used common /2 cable, in which the colors are black and white.  White is usually neutral, but not here.   To reduce confusion, the rule is that the *always-hot* must be white, to make it more obvious to people with voltage testers that this isn't neutral.  The black, then, is *switched-hot*.

The white in the black bundle goes to a cable.  The black in that cable, which you have not mentioned yet, is the *switched-hot*.  That connects to the lamp's black wire.

The group of all-white wires are actual **neutral**.  Those wires are doing important tasks.  However, your lamp needs neutral, so its white needs to be **added** to that bundle.